# Как добавить поле с датой в Drupal

Tags: drupal

Добрый день.
Каким-то образом в Drupal'е можно добавить дату в новость?
Вот например [сюда](http://nineteenfifteen.prototype-interactive.com/node/68), в контенте под картинкой справа стоит дата, она указана статично просто через редактор, можно ли как-то настроить Drupal чтобы при добавлении новости эта дата устанавливалась туда автоматически?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заходите под админом на страницу с новостью, жмете [edit] над нужным блоком, открывается админка с редактированием блока/ноды. 
Жмете плюсик рядом с fields в контенте. Открываестя панель со всеми возможными переменными. Выбираете node.postdate

Comment: хм, нажимаю edit - открывается админка не с редактированием блока/ноды а с самим контентом.
вот такое: http://s2.ipicture.ru/Gallery/Viewfull/12508679.html

Comment: Хм. Я не узнаю вас в гриме. Что за версия Друпала?

Answer (score 1):

- Если у вас по умолчанию не показывает дата, то идем : Структура->тип Материала ->Ваш тип(новости). --> "Управление  отображения", там и указываем поле дата(если нет то надо создать в -->"Управление полями" данного типа).
- уже потом выставляем нужную дату в самой контенте, как сказал [[@knes](/users/2825/knes)](/users/2825/knes).

Answer (score 1):

1. Установите модуль [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/Date), который предоставляет разные варианты поля с датой.
2. Откройте /admin/structure/types/manage/[ваш тип контента]/fields
3. Добавьте новое поле типа date (там их 3 варианта).
4. Настройте виджет (время нужно отключить).
5. Сохраните изменения и проверьте результат.